# New-answer live notification is faster than submitting the answer

Tags: bug, answers, live-refresh, posting

When Stackoverflow is sluggish (or is it just me?), I sometimes get the "*1 new answer has been posted*" live (websocket?) notification **for my own answer** while the page is still loading after I submitted the form:

[image]

Can we disable this, please - by showing the notification only to those users who are not the author of said answer?

Comment: lol, that's pretty great...

Comment: I believed only Chuck Norris can answer a question before Chuck Norris. But that seem to be false...

Comment: Don't forget Jon Skeet.

Comment: @FlorinGhita: [Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) can [get upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/343862/1048572) on posts while he is still answering

Comment: What if you open the same question in two browser windows and post answer in one of them. Should the notification appear in another one?

Comment: I've also noticed that a couple of times, though it's been some time since I saw that last.